# Writing Excel file having conflicts with another user

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I have tried several of the solutions I have seen out here, but am still having a problem writing an Excel file.

I have a template xlsx file that I initially copy to a working file to get started.  I then have a block like this

```
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";",
        outputfileName)))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
```

followed by a series of

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Eventualy, before the using block closes, I have

```
        connection.Close( );
    }
```

At this point, my app appears to be hanging on to the Excel file.  If I try to open it either manually or via `System.Diagnostics.Process`, I get "file is locked for editing by 'another user'" and even if I respond "OK", I still see only the blank template.

When I actually exit my app, then the Excel file seems to be complete and accessible.  Apparently, closing the connection is not enough to flush the buffer and release the file.

What I would like to understand is how to release my hold on the file, so that I can actually have my app give the user a chance to use Process to open the file for him or to open it manually if he prefers.

Comment: try using FileStream.Unlock Method check this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.unlock%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found EPPlus, which is easy to use and doesn't open Excel at all, so this resolved the locking issue.  This doesn't actually answer the question, but it is an acceptable work-around, especially because writing to EPPlus is much easier than writing to Excel via OLEDB.